# Visual Studio Installer Project Custom Action based on Build Configuration

Tags: visual-studio-2017, custom-action, visual-studio-setup-proje, buildconfiguration, vdproj

Is it possible in an Installer Project to conditionally run a Custom Action based on the project build configuration (e.g. Debug, Release, etc.)?

Also to include/exclude files based on the Build Configuration?

Can I do any of these in Visual Studio 2017 or by manually editing the .vdproj file?

Comment: If your .msi file name is different between release and debug builds (like mysetup.msi and mysetupdebug.msi for example), you can use that as Windows Installer conditions (for custom action and file)

Comment: Could you write a sample code how to achieve this? I can't find anything on it by googling it.

Comment: There is no difference between release and debug builds of an MSI. There is no added "debug" information. What is it that you hope to achieve with the idea that the builds are different? Is there an actual underlying problem that you believe this debug/release idea will solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have defined your project, let's suppose the custom action is a .NET installer project (it's not mandatory, but it's like that in my sample).

Just go the the list of Custom Actions (right-click on Project/View/Custom Actions), select your special custom action, and in the "Condition" property in the property grid, you can use the following test:

```
  OriginalDatabase >< "Debug"
```

The funny syntax (>< means "contains") is documented in [Conditional Statement Syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368012.aspx), `OriginalDatabase` (case-sensitive) is a property that contains the full path name of the .msi file path that's being installed.

This is documented in Windows Installer's [Property Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370905.aspx). You can use this type of syntax in all `Condition` properties that are defined on various items (custom actions, files, etc.). Note "Debug" may be too simple as a discriminant piece of text, but you get the idea.

[image]

Of course, that supposes you've changed the .msi output name to include the "Debug" text, in Debug configuration, something like this:

[image]

Another option would be to always embed the custom action, but do nothing in it if some property is set (to indicate release mode for example). You can use `CustomActionData` to pass information to custom actions.